# Python - Replace parenthesis with periods and remove first and last period

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to take an input file with a list of DNS lookups that contains subdomain/domain separators with the string length in parenthesis as opposed to periods.  It looks like this:

```
(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)
(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)
(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)
```

I would like to replace the parenthesis and numbers with periods and then remove the first and last period.  My code currently does this, but leaves the last period.  Any help is appreciated.  Here is the code:

```
import re

file = open('test.txt', 'rb')
writer = open('outfile.txt', 'wb')


for line in file:
    newline1 = re.sub(r"\(\d+\)",".",line)  
    if newline1.startswith('.'):
        newline1 = newline1[1:-1]   

    writer.write(newline1)
```

Comment: it does not leave the last period for me. Is this the exact code you are trying?

Comment: there is no need to leave the file IO in the sample code; you're only asking about the string replacement bit not reading and writing files. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @ErikAllik But now `file` is a single string, rather than an iterable of strings. `for line in file` will iterate through each character individually.

Comment: Thanks, that ought to do it :-)

Comment: BTW, `file` isn't a great choice for a variable name as it shadows the Python 2 built-in `file` type. This isn't as bad as shadowing `str`, `list`, etc, because it's so rare to use `file` directly, but still...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the lines with `\(\d+\)` regex and then join with `.` stripping commas at both ends:

```
for line in file:
    res =".".join(re.split(r'\(\d+\)', line))
    writer.write(res.strip('.'))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0oscFJ)

Comment: Just FYI: so as not to "shadow" `file`, I'd recommend to use `file_str` or `file_contents`.

Answer (score 3):

Given that your `re.sub` call works like this:

```
> re.sub(r"\(\d+\)",".", "(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)")
'.subdomain.domain.com.'
```

the only thing you need to do is strip the resulting string from any leading and trailing `.`:

```
> s = re.sub(r"\(\d+\)",".", "(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)")
> s.strip(".")
'subdomain.domain.com'
```

---

**Full drop in solution:**

```
for line in file:
    newline1 = re.sub(r"\(\d+\)",".",line).strip(".")
    writer.write(newline1)
```

Comment: I think strip is more flexible, in case of a different delimiter or missing delimiters on either end, but you could also just slice the string:  s = s[1:-1] or similar, assuming that the delimiters are always there.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1):
        return "."
    else:
        return ""



x="(8)subdomain(5)domain(3)com(0)"
print re.sub(r"^\(\d+\)|((?<!^)\(\d+\))(?!$)|\(\d+\)$",repl,x)
```

Output:`subdomain.domain.com`.

You can define your own `replace` function.

Comment: The issue with this answer is not python related: the guy only needs the `.strip(".")` bit and you're proposing an overly complicated regular expression together with a custom replacement function.

Comment: @ErikAllik my point was to show how we can define our own `replace` function.This case may be simple but in complex scenarios this is the correct method

Comment: well in this case, the use of a custom replace function (together with an overcomplicated regexp) is clearly contraindicated; it doesn't matter if it's generally useful knowledge if the way you present it is totally misleading.

Comment: This approach - however "hard" it may look like - is working here, just tested. This is actually a smart way of using look-arounds to match parenthetical numerals inside a string at 3 specific location types.

Comment: Answers are very often downvoted not because they are incorrect but they are misleading or overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

for line in file:
    line = re.sub(r'\(\d\)','.',line)

line = line.strip('.')
```